# Space not taking when displaying value in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am entering some text in a input box. When entering a text I am giving some spaces means 
more then 1 space just say 4 or 5. But when I get the value from the input box and append to 
a div. It replaces all extra spaces with once single space.

Example, I enter text like this.
  **"Hi      can   you please look    on   it      ?"**

then if get the value using `$("#inpuboxid").val();`
 then append that value to div.

it become like this:    **"Hi can you please look on it ?"**

How to achieve this, as browser automatically replaces extra spaces with once space

Comment: Ironically, stackoverflow does the same thing :p

Comment: insert `&nbsp;` instead of space. and try again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503001/multiple-spaces-between-words-in-html-without-nbsp

Comment: @MWay What stackoverflow does the same ?

Comment: @SureshBora Before your edit, stackoverflow also removed the spaces...

Comment: @MWay :) you really have egle eyes Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML squishes adjacent spaces together by default. Add a style of "white-space: pre;" to your div. This should keep all the white space in its contents.

```
<div style="white-space: pre;">Hi    can  you please look    on  it     ?</div>
```

### [See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvp8r/)

Comment: Thanks, Anthony Chu. Worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

After you set the text of the element, you can use the html method to replace spaces with `&nbsp;`. 
Here is an example.

```
$("#somelement").text($("#inpuboxid").val()).html(function(index,html){return html.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');})
```