# Read and print with \t in PHP

Tags: php, string, io, fgets

I'm opening a TXT file in **PHP** and want to read the lines of it one by one.

I'm using `fgets()` .

The problem is that the output is ignoring the tabulations ("\t") in the original file, which is not what I want.

There is some way **to force PHP to don't ignore 'em**?

My code:

```
$file = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("<br><br>Error.");
while (!feof($file)) {
    $string = fgets($file, 4096);
    echo "<br> " . $string;
}
```

Comment: use something like `preg_replace` or `str_replace` to turn the `\t` into something that's more useful to you, such as (4 spaces)

Comment: php doesn't change  or ignore the data. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: PHP is **NOT** ignoring anything, your web browser is. Press `Ctrl + u` to see the source code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Spaces Between Words in HTML without &nbsp;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503001/multiple-spaces-between-words-in-html-without-nbsp) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571648/html-tab-space-instead-of-multiple-non-breaking-spaces-nbsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (probably everyone's for that matter) web browser is ignoring the tabs.

Try this:

```
$file = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("<br><br>Error.");
echo '<pre>'
while (!feof($file)) {
    $string = fgets($file, 4096);
    echo "\n" . htmlentities($string);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

or

```
$file = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("<br><br>Error.");
echo '<textarea>'
while (!feof($file)) {
    $string = fgets($file, 4096);
    echo "\n" . htmlentities($string);
}
echo '</textarea>';
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you.