# react-json-view trims all white space from string

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, string, json-view

I use a "react-json-view" to display a json. The problem is, the library trims all white spaces in delivered strings.

I have a data with valid json:

```
{
   title: "some title                 end of title"
}
```

And I receive output in my json component:

```
{
   title: "some title end of title"
}
```

Is there a way to get this json in the original shape?
In code inspector there is a original json with spaces - only in react-json-view component the data is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is actually html- and CSS based!

I'll assume your react-json-view creates a div with some text in it like so:

```html
<div class="react-json-view">
...
</div>
```

Now, to fix this, you'll simply need to add a [CSS whitespace-modifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to this.

CSS:

```
.react-json-view {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Source: [Multiple Spaces Between Words in HTML without &nbsp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503001/multiple-spaces-between-words-in-html-without-nbsp)